# Set sensitivity of microphone from menu bar

Tags: menu-bar, microphone

Is there a way to disable the microphone by setting the sensitivity to zero from the menu bar on El Capitan?  Is there a keystroke option?

If I use ⌥ click (option+click) I can see the see the microphone option, but clicking on it doesn't do anything.  It's always checked.  I have to go into Sound preferences to set the sensitivity to zero.

[image: Menu bar item dropdown]

Comment: What do you mean by disable? How are you ‘disabling’ it in System Preferences?

Comment: @grgarside Turning the sensitivity all the way down.

Comment: Well that doesn't disable it, the ⌥-click on the volume menu bar item is just a device switcher. Perhaps someone will offer a suitable solution for adjusting the sensitivity from a menu bar item.